# How to read csv file having columns matching with list of similar columns names (not exact column names)

Tags: python, dataframe, csv

Suppose I have a csv file with columns as `"A__123","B__324","C__599","D__232","E__235"`.

`columns_to_read = ["A","C","E"]`

Now I want to read only columns in list `columns_to_read`

How can I read the csv based on the above condition.

I know I can use `usecols` to read the specific columns of csv but how can I read similar columns?

Answer (score 0):

I don't include the reading from the csv, but i will do it like this, when you get lists as return values from reading the `.csv` file

```
test_data = ["A_123", "B_324", "C_599", "D_232", "E_235"]

columns_to_read = ["A", "C", "E"]

for i in range(len(test_data)):
    for j in range(len(columns_to_read)):
        if (columns_to_read[j] in test_data[i]):
            print(test_data[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this.

```
`df = read_csv("file.csv")
col_name1 = []
col_name2 = []
for i in range(1,len(df)):
    col_name1.append(df[i][0])#0 is the index of the column.
    col_name2.append(df[i][1])
`
```

and then merge the code in one dataframe like so

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(col_name1,col_name2)),columns=['Column_name1','Column_name2])
```

refer to https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/zip-in-python/ for `zip()` function.
refer to https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/list for `list()` function.
`pd.DataFrame()` is used to create dataframe.